# How to add extra field to biblatex?

Tags: biblatex

Using biblatex

```
\usepackage[style=ieee, backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
```

And I am trying to add publisher to the phd type but it does not add it.

```
@phdthesis{phd,
  author = "Me",
  title = "My Title",
  school = "My University",
  year = 2020,
  publisher= "Fubar",
  type     = {PHD}
 }
```

How do I add publisher to my reference?

Comment: Have you tried `note= "Fubar"` instead of `publisher= "Fubar"`? Aside: Most Ph.D. dissertations don't have publishers. If yours is published in book form, you may want to consider switching from the `@phdthesis` entry type to the `@book` entry type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the BibTeX and `biblatex` tradition theses (`@phthesis`, `@thesis`, ...) don't have a `publisher`. Instead they have a `institution` or `school`. Most dissertations can probably be found without giving the publisher (if they are published by a known publishing house at all).

That all said, it is certainly not impossible to add a `publisher` to theses. You just need to find a good place to hook in to. The bibliography output of the `ieee` style is based on the standard `biblatex` style `standard.bbx`, where the institution of a `@thesis` is printed in `institution+location+date`. You can modify that macro to also print a `publisher`.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=ieee]{biblatex}

\renewbibmacro*{institution+location+date}{%
  \ifentrytype{thesis}
    {\printlist{publisher}%
     \setunit{\addcomma\space}}
    {}%
  \printlist{location}%
  \iflistundef{institution}
    {\setunit*{\addcomma\space}}
    {\setunit*{\addcolon\space}}%
  \printlist{institution}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@phdthesis{phd,
  author    = {Me},
  title     = {My Title},
  school    = {My University},
  year      = 2020,
  publisher = {Fubar},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \cite{phd}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Me, ‘My title,’ Ph.D. dissertation, Fubar, My University, 2020.]

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use `@phdthesis` and choose `@thesis` instead (but for this example I'm going to use `@phdthesis`). Also I would recommend dropping `bibtex` as backend and instead employ `biber`.

Your problem can be solved by assigning a `type` and a `note` to the thesis-entry:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{demo-phd.bib}
@phdthesis{phd,
  author = {Lastname, Firstname},
  title = {Awesome Title},
  school = {Some University},
  year = {2020},
  publisher= {Fubar},
  type = {Published by Fubar},
  note = {Ph.D. dissertation}
 }
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[style=ieee, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{demo-phd.bib}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}

There is this great thesis I'd really like to quote: \autocite{phd}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
\end{document}
```

[image: type and note]

Comment: It's a bit meh that you essentially have to invert the fields `note` and `type` here to get a nicer output. (Generally `type` would contain something like 'PhD thesis' and not would be for further notes.) An alternative for `note` could be `addendum` or in this case even `pubstate`. Those fields are printed after `type`.

Comment: `@phdthesis` is a (legacy/convenience) alias in `biblatex`. It gets mapped to `@thesis` with `type = {phdthesis},` (only if the `type` field is empty, if it is present it is not overwritten). So in your MWE it doesn't matter if you use `@thesis` or `@phdthesis`, since you give the `type` yourself, but in general `@phdthesis` is a bit shorter than specifying `type = {phdthesis},` if you use `@thesis`.

Comment: @moewe, `pubstate` is placed last (even after the year), so there would be tweaking involved. With `addendum` it's the same story, so I best delete the anwer altogether. Would you agree?

Comment: The question is whether it is bad that the publisher info is placed after the year. I don't see any specification about the exact place in the question. I wouldn't have a problem with having an addendum like 'published by ...' after the year. But I think that your inversion of `type` and `note`, while semantically questionable, gives much better output than if you had stuck to the more semantically sound `type = {phdthesis}, note = {Ph.D. dissertation}`. Sometimes it can be useful to abuse the semantics a bit if you are aware of the fact that you are doing it.

Comment: @moewe, I really like the gentle way, you keep correcting me. You've also managed to convince me to read the entire `biblatex`-documentation now. Uhm, thanks for that ;-)

Comment: To be honest, I don't know if reading the `biblatex` documentation in one go is a good use of anyone's time. For the most part it is a reference that documents all interfaces and commands of the package rather than a user guide. So it won't be a particularly exciting read. Some of the introductions mentioned in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13509/35864 also cover intermediate topics and are a much nicer read (I'm especially thinking about Paul Stanley's https://github.com/PaulStanley/biblatex-tutorial)

Comment: @moewe, great! I'll check your recommendations out, thank you!